# Periodical execution of function without halting other operations

Tags: python-3.x

I want to update a variable every 24 hours without halting actions in while loop. I used `.sleep()` method in function, but it halted the other operations in while loop. To be clear, I want in each while loop execution, if "updated_list" values belong to more than 24 hours ago, it updates; else, the loop continues other operations with the last value.

```
def updater():
    list = ["list of variables from bunch of API calls which I want to be updated every 24 hours"]
    return list

while True:
    updated_list = updater()
    #Do other operations on updated_list without being paused for 24 hours!#
```

Comment: If you need a program to run 24/7 and you're thinking about updating a variable once every 24 hours, maybe it's time to rethink how you're doing things. Maybe it makes more sense to schedule a dedicate piece of code that runs your update every 24 hours (using cron or the like), and then simply run applications that fetch the most recent data they need before they do their work.

Comment: Good hint, tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this might be to schedule a single piece of code of which the only purpose is to fetch API data using something like `cron`. Then the code would get updated every 24 hours. You could then run programs that get that data and use it.

Comment: tnx. It doesn't help. it halts execution of other operations. I think @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is right and there is no way to handle it in a single shell.

Comment: @AmirDaghestani Yes, that might be the only way to get this to work.